# How can I remove unneeded command line options when building with gcc in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, clang, openmp

I have got a project that I used to build with cmake and the default Apple compiler. Now, to make use of OpenMP in that project I needed to change to an OpenMp enabled compiler. 
So I installed gcc via Homebrew and also installed the Xcode 6 plugin. (http://hamelot.co.uk/programming/add-gcc-compiler-to-xcode-6/)

My OpenMp related errors are now gone. I am left with this error which I don't know how to get rid off:

```
gcc-5: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wmost'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change cmake's default set of flags passed on to the compiler by setting `<CMAKE_C_FLAGS>` and `<CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS>` variables.

If you search for "Wmost" in your project's cmake files and in cmake's shared/Modules directory you may find where it is set, and negate appropriately.

Comment: One less favorable but nonetheless possible way is to `STR_REPLACE` `-Wmost` out of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` (e.g. `STRING(REPLACE "-Wmost" "" tempVar ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}); set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${tempVar});`